# Print different array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I want to display different string array elements like this:

- Clubs 1
- Hearts Ace
- Diamonds 9

CardGame.java:

```
public class CardGame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
        String[] deck = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                        "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Aces" };

        int i = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
        int j = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );


        for( int a = 0; a < 7; a++ ) {
            System.out.println( "Deck " + deck[i] + " Suit " + suit[j] );
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

How will I do it? Point me to correct logic of displaying those different elements. Thanks.

Comment: Well, look at where you're looping... and then look at where you're setting the values of `i` and `j`. How do you expect what you're printing to change if `i` and `j` don't change? (Also note that your arrays are misnamed. The *suits* are hearts, clubs, diamonds and spades...

Comment: You want to display all the possible combinations and in random order ?

Comment: @KaipaMSarma yup I want them random and the possible combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int times = 10; // Say you want it 10 times, in your code it's 7.

    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.println(deck[(int) (Math.random() * deck.length)]
                 + " : " + suit[(int) (Math.random() * suit.length)]);
    }
```

Comment: Good one liner ;) I salute you sir.

Answer (score 3):

put

```
int i = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
int j = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );
```

into the `for` loop, so that in every iteration a new random card is generated

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CardGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         String[] deck = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
         String[] suit = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Aces" };

         for( int a = 0; a < 7; a++ ) {
             int i = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
             int j = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );

             System.out.println( "Deck " + deck[i] + " Suit " + suit[j] );
         }
         System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CardGame { 

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        String[] deck = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades" }; 
        String[] suit = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
                                    "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Aces" }; 

        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
        int totalCards=0;

        while(s.size() < (deck.length * suit.length)){ 
            int i = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length ); 
            int j = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length ); 

            if(!s.contains("Deck " + deck[i] + " Suit " + suit[j])){
                s.add("Deck " + deck[i] + " Suit " + suit[j]);
                totalCards++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Cards at Random: ");
        for(String str: s)
        System.out.println(str); 

        System.out.println("Total Cards: "+ totalCards);
    } 
}
```

This will return all 52 cards( all combinations) randomly

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question - if you want many random cards, or all of them.

All of them:

```
for (String cardSuit: suit) {
    for (String cardDeck: deck) {
        System.out.println(cardDeck + " " + cardSuit);
    }
}
```

Random (given number):

```
Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    String cardSuit = suit[rnd.nextInt(suit.length)],
           cardDeck = deck[rnd.nextInt(deck.length)];
    System.out.println(cardDeck + " " + cardSuit);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've forgot to access the array. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
int j = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );
```

put into for loop because your  new generate i j value get