# Randomizing in Java

Tags: java, random

I have 4 Strings to represent people and 4 Strings to represent names.

I'm trying to randomize them so that every time I start my application, my four people will have different names, but no one can have the same name during runtime.

Example:

```
String person_one;
String person_two;
String person_three;
String person_four;

String name_one = "Bob";
String name_two = "Jane";
String name_three = "Tim";
String name_four = "Sara";
```

Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Look up modulo, and the [random generation in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902124/generation-of-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Have you ever done anything similar, in another language or with different data that you think could be useful here?

Comment: Put them in an array and shuffle it.

Comment: You could look at my earlier answer which is similar to this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12795958/713414

Comment: It makes sense.. it's just a little trickier than first-glance suggests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29):

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Bob");
names.add("Jane");
names.add("Tim");
names.add("Sara");

Collections.shuffle(names);

person_one = names.get(0);
person_two = names.get(1);
person_three = names.get(2);
person_four = names.get(3);
```

Comment: This is awesome. Had no idea java had something like this. Perfect. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Joey You might want to use `names.get(i)` instead of `names[i]` and `Collections.shuffle(names)` instead of `names.shuffle()` ;)

Comment: Baz: Argh, that's what I get for a Java detour while doing C# :-)

Comment: @EGHDK Java has one of the most complete and best thought out APIs there is.

Comment: user1598390, that may well be subject to debate. A lot of places in Java's APIs are horrible.

Comment: @Joey I love Java for it's character, not for its perfection. :P It would be boring without those horrible places...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).